# Pet Mouse is Biting

Tags: biting, mice

So, I recently gotten a male pet mouse, and I left him alone for 3 days, before I started to try and tame him. He is able to take food from my hand, and is willing to sniff my hand, however, he has been biting me whenever my hand is nearby. If I'm cleaning the cage for example, he will bite a lot until I move my hand away. I know its not mouse biting as in him trying to find out if I'm food or not, because I felt those bites initially, and it wasn't painful, as in, it almost caused me to bleed. I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to stop him from biting, as I don't want to return him where I got him, since he gotten a lot of bite marks from the other mice he was with before.

Comment: Updates on the situtation, he has begun to bite me to the point of bleeding heavily, I am honestly not sure if I should return him, since after he bit me, my parents want me to return him. After that, whenever I am near him he will bite me always till I bleed. I have no clue what to do, since I heard mice dont usually bite, and definetely not to the point of causing bleeding to occur. Please help, I looked at forums and tried everything.